Neo4j Connector for Kafka in a Kubernetes environment
I have a Kafka cluster deployed in Kubernetes, and my Neo4j database is hosted in the cloud. However, I can't find an official Neo4j Kafka Connector image or any documentation on deploying the connector in Kubernetes.
How should I set up the Neo4j Kafka Connector to integrate with my Kafka cluster in this environment?
